# SSL Certificate to custom domain in Azure

Tags: azure, ssl

Attempting to follow the instructions in [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-purchase-ssl-web-site#verify-domain-ownership).

I have an app service app in Azure that has my custom domain associated with it (already verified in the Azure App; I can go to the URL and see my site once I pass through Chrome's "This site isn't protected by SSL" warning), so when the certificate asked me to verify ownership of the domain I chose the default option of App Service Verification. I get the message in the corner of my screen "Create Domain Verification Token: Successfully updated all the apps with the Domain Verification Token". However, on the current screen "Domain Verification" within the certificate, I still see the message "Domain Verification Pending. Verify operations may take 5-10 minutes to take effect" (been at this for probably 45 minutes).

I wait, I retry, I wait, still nothing. No worries, I'll just use manual verification via the DNS configuration (using Google Domains). When I head there, I attempt to create a TXT resource with the value set equal to the Domain Verification Token. I get the error message "Record already in use".

I'm not sure how to see where the record is already in use. Any ideas on how to do this and then unlink it so I can create the TXT in my DNS configuration? Alternatively, if I'm missing a crucial step in the App Service Validation piece and that can be made to work, that would also be grand.

Can add screenshots if those would help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out - I was unaware that the DNS configuration could only support one TXT resource record at a time. I had used a TXT record previously to verify the domain in Azure, so when I was trying to verify ownership of the SSL Certificate via a new TXT record, it wouldn't let me create a new one.

Once I read up on that, I just had to delete the TXT record for domain verification (it's not needed once verification is complete, though the A record needs to stick around). I was then able to create the new TXT record and verify the certificate. Woohoo!

Answer (score 0):

Did you also create a A record? You have to create a A record and TXT Record for custom domain validation

Comment: The custom domain validation isn't the issue; I've already done that. Edited my answer to make that a little more clear. The issue is that the SSL certificate I purchased through Azure won't verify via the App Service Verification method, and when I've tried manually (last night and again just now) via my DNS configuration, I get the error message "Record already in use"